# Árboles Binarios

Tags: java, árboles-binarios, binario

hoy en la escuela empecé a ver los árboles binarios pero al estar haciendo una practica me surgió una duda. De un nodo que se determina como raíz o padre cuantos otros nodos hijos pueden salir yo tengo entendido que solo otros dos uno a la izquierda y otro  a la derecha como se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero la duda es que si puede pasar esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comento los árboles binarios son los que tiene orden 2 y esto significa que cada nodo ***(padre)*** puede tener como máximo 2 nodos ***(hijos)***. Pero para mayor información revisa este tutorial. [Tutorial de árboles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVCNzj5BMcs).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo resolviste mi duda eso me estaba causando confusión.

Comment: @Torniceli601 recuerda que si la respuesta te fue de utilidad la mejor forma de agradecer es votarle positivo o marcarla como aceptada. Saludos